# VB.Net to C# Replace

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'd like to rewrite my application from VB.Net to C# (I'm beginner in C#)

The VB Code

```
If Prc1 <> 0 Then 
Me.PrcBox1.Text = Replace(Format(System.Math.Round((Prc1), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), ), ",", ".") 
Else 
Me.PrcBox1.Text = ""
```

My C# try

```
if (Prc1 != 0)
   PrcBox1.Text = string.Replace(string.Format(Math.Round((Prc1), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), ), ",", ".");
else
   PrcBox1.Text = "";
```

The error occurs here between

```
--> <-- :  .....AwayFromZero), **--> ), <--**  ....
```

as invalid expression

Comment: What namespace/class/enum is MidpointRounding in? You need to actually specify this in C# as, save for the `dynamic` keyword, C# is fully static typed.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Convert the text in the TextBox to decimal and round it to 3 digits ?

Comment: Yeah. VB.NET is statically typed, too, @Paul. The MidpointRounding enum is defined in the System namespace. The basic using/imports directives included by the default template should be enough to make this work. The real problem looks like an unqualified call to Replace, which should never have worked in VB.NET, either. Along with other syntax errors. I can't see how the original code would have compiled. You have to fix that first before you go translating it.

Comment: `, ), ` -- this is illegal. Just put a necessary value here (right before the `)`) to make the syntax legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this out:

```
PrcBox1.Text = string.Replace(
                 string.Format(
                     Math.Round(
                       (Prc1), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
                     ), 
                 ), -- end of string.format - missing second parameter
               "," , "." -- for string replace
               )
```

It appears string.format is missing a parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The function that you used in the VB code is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format` which is a bit different than `string.Format`

You can try

```
this.PrcBox1.Text = System.Math.Round(Prc1, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                                                      .ToString("#,##0").Replace(',', '.');
```

or just add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to use the VB functions :

```
using vb = Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

and then

```
this.PrcBox1.Text = vb.String.Replace( vb.String.Format(
                  System.Math.Round(Prc1, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)), ",", ".");
```

Also, in C# you can not leave optional parameters blank as in VB,
 so `Format(value, )` in VB has to be `Format(value)` in C#

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error. You can't call `String.Replace`, it is not a static method and it needs an object to call it on and can't be called directly from the type `String`.

The nesting made your life harder, try to break down the functions and then put them back together:

```
double doubleVal = Math.Round(Prc1, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
sPrcBox1.Text = doubleVal.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
```

Then:

```
PrcBox1.Text = (Math.Round((Prc1), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: Please explain what was the bug and how you fixed it. `This should work` doesn't say anything to me.

Comment: @Eser Sorry, i was adding the description.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some misplaced brackets, which is what is giving you the invalid expression error. Try this

```
PrcBox1.Text = string.Replace(string.Format(Math.Round(Prc1), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),  ",", ".");
```